Exporting SAS dataset to CSV, introducing blank lines in next row, which makes as if record is missing
Exporting a dataset with 530 column and 68531 records but because of one column the whole dataset increases to 123481 records
SAS dataset where one of the column have multiple sentence with empty space and next line, while exporting this as proc export to CSV introduces blank lines in the next row also pushes the next sentence to the next line and so on,
Tried ODS but it gets out of memory
enter code here




Looks like there are Carriage Returns / Line Feeds in the value?

How did you "export" the dataset to CSV?  Why did you post pictures of spreadsheets instead of the text of the CSV file?

This may help you solve the issue.
data shoes;
   set sashelp.shoes;
   array C _CHARACTER_;
   do over c;
      c = compress(c,'0A0D'x,'C');
      end;
   run;


I ran a little data step to see what characters COMPRESS thinks are control characters and I found these 39 characters: 000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F101112131415161718191A1B1C1D1E1F7F818D8F909DAD

@Tom I figured that 0a and 0d were control characters.  Raincoat and umbrella.

compress syntax worked but just used the datastep as below instead do

Your data has embedded carriage returns. You can replace them with something like a / so that people know that it's part of a new paragraph.
data fixed;
    set have;
    col2 = tranwrd(col2, '0D0A'x, '/');
run;


i have just replaced tranwrd to compress ref_referralreasons = compress(ref_referralreasons, '0D0A'x, 'C'); this worked

The issue is that the value of one of your characters variables (or the formatted value of a numeric variable) contains the end of line marker.
Note that if you tell SAS to use CRLF combination as the end of line marker and then use only CR (or LF) as a split character in your variable values then the generated SAS file will be readable.
Some software, like EXCEL, can read CSV files with end of line markers embedded in cell values IF the value is quoted.  But the PUT statement with the DSD option (which is what PROC EXPORT uses) does not know to quote values that have end of line markers in them.
If you want to export your file as it is you could try using this macro: https://github.com/sasutils/macros/blob/master/safe_ds2csv.sas
But note that there is performance impact on checking every value before writing it.  And you might need to modify the default value for the MAXCHAR parameter if you have string values that are longer then 300 bytes, which will make it run even slower.
